# Arduino Mega and ADS1256 board

Tags: arduino-mega, spi, adc

I found code for a Teensy board and now I added just digitalwriteFast library to code and changed port to SPI for Arduino Mega. And now I get just one number out:

```
#include <SPI.h>
#include <digitalWriteFast.h>


//(other stuff for getting the ADS1526 to work is in the next tab
#define ADS_RST_PIN    48 //ADS1256 reset pin
#define ADS_RDY_PIN    47 //ADS1256 data ready
#define ADS_CS_PIN    46 //ADS1256 chip select

/* 
CLK  - pin 52
DIN  - pin 50 (MOSI)
DOUT - pin 51 (MISO)
*/


//put the ADC constants here

double resolution = 8388608.; //2^23-1

//this needs to match the setting in the ADC init function in the library tab
double Gain = 64.; //be sure to have a period 

double vRef = 5.0; //reference voltage

//we'll calculate this in setup
double bitToVolt = 0.;

void setup() {
 delay(1000);
 Serial.begin(115200);
 Serial.println("booting");
 //initialize the ADS
 pinMode(ADS_CS_PIN, OUTPUT);

 pinMode(ADS_RDY_PIN, INPUT);
 pinMode(ADS_RST_PIN, OUTPUT);

 SPI.begin();

 initADS();
 Serial.println("done init");

 //determine the conversion factor
    //do some calculations for the constants
 bitToVolt = resolution*Gain/vRef;
}

int32_t val1;
int32_t val2;
int32_t val3;

void loop() {
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:

double value = 0;
for (int i = 0; i <1; i++){
 read_three_values();
 value += val1;
}

value /=1.;

 Serial.print(value,8);
 Serial.print("\t");
 Serial.print(val2);
 Serial.print("\t");
 Serial.println(val3);

//
//double value = 0;
//for (int i = 0; i <10; i++){
//  value += read_Value();
//}
//
//value /= 10.;
//value /= bitToVolt;
//
//Serial.println(value,11); 
}
```

I don't know where to connect PDWN pin?

And I have this board:
https://www.ebay.com/itm/NEW-1PC-ADS1256-high-precision-ADC-module-conversion-24-bit-eight-channel/292541380872?hash=item441cd33908:g:uYUAAOSwLpda5BIZ:rk:1:pf:0

Greetings Matej

Comment: Please show us a working sketch. The sync/pdwn can be connected to 3.3v or also to 5v since it is 5v tolerant. It is in the datasheet. The spi bus is 5v tolerant but the data out (MISO on the arduino board) signal is only 3.3v. It will probably work, but a 3.3v arduino board is better. At ebay they say that also a dac8532 is on the board, but I can't see that in the photos. I can only see a ads1256 and a 2.5v voltage reference and a voltage regualator. It is a very nice and very cheap module, but without schematic you have to guess how to connect it.

Comment: no schematic came with it.

Comment: i use this code link is here https://github.com/mbilsky/TeensyADS1256

Comment: That code uses an interrupt for the ADS_RDY_PIN, but the arduino mega 2560 does not have an interrupt at pin 47. There is also no `digitalPinToInterrupt()` for the interrupt pin (the arduino mega 2560 needs that, the teensy does not). You can fix that, but I suggest to find a more basic simple library for the ads1256. You need to make it work in a basic way before trying a library that is optimized for speed.

Comment: Ok but will i reach 30000SPS with other library